# Given a URL to a JavaScript file, compile, and return result in response

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

As per title, given a URL to a JavaScript file, is it possible to get webpack to compile and return the result during runtime?

**Update: I am able to retrieve the file, but once I have the file, I am not sure how to feed it into the compiler (step 3 in the scenario above).**

**Scenario**

1. HTTP Request is received by server (e.g. express) containing the request URL to a JavaScript file.
2. Assume I am able to retrieve the JavaScript file or its filepath.
3. Feed JavaScript file into webpack compiler.
4. Webpack compiler processes the JavaScript file and outputs result.
5. Result is returned in a HTTP Response containing a URL to the output (the webpack processed javascript file).

I looked around for solutions using webpack-dev-middleware and compiler API but am not able to find a way to do this.

**Updated: Pseudo Code**

```
const middleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(middleware(compiler, { ...middleware config... }))
app.use((req, res) => {
    const jsFile = fetchSync(req.url);
    // How do I write actual code to accomplish the logic below?
    compiler.compile(jsFile).then((output) => { res.send(output.url) });
});
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague, at least it is exactly clear with which part you have what problem. You should show what you have tried so far and explain at which point you have a problem and what that problem is.

Comment: May be you can catch the url for the js file in express, and use runtime api of webpack https://webpack.js.org/api/node/ to process the file and send the response with proper content-type header, so that browser can process it as js file. Just an idea to start working on :D

Comment: running the node api is the way to go + express.

Comment: I have updated with the point I have the problem with, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Try reading webpack-cli codebase (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/bin/cli.js#L441), they use webpack node api, basically the file has to go into the entry-point on your "options" obj.

Comment: you might have to save it temporarily locally.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear with my question, I am able to retrieve the file, I am not sure how to then feed it into the webpack compiler.

Comment: @PlayMa256 Is there a way to add an entry point during runtime, after the compiler object has been created?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to _do_ here. Why is webpack required at all if it's a proper javascript file already? (why not make your server run the script directly?) Alternatively, if the URL is "a js file" but the _data_ should be the result of a webpack operation, then make your server run webpack in code, not cli, with a config that you wrote so you know which file it's going to write to, then when webpack finishes render the content from that file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the compiled code will be later returned to be used in a script tag src attribute for a functional test, the javascript file is only known at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain what your step 5 is supposed to mean? The user's browser is still waiting for a response from its `GET /someurl.js` from step 1.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans step 5 is supposed to return the result in a http response.

Comment: yeah but why on earth would it return "a url", just make it return the actual data? I've left an answer but what you're trying to do sounds super weird. When the browser does "GET file.js", your server's response should be javascript code. Whether it has to spend a few seconds running webpack to generate that JS or not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the url is used in a script element's src attribute and evaluated in a html file

Comment: Apologies, will post some code on my browserify implementation which I am trying to convert to webpack in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward, but without you showing *actual* code, this is the best I can give you:

```
var fs = require('fs'); // or fs-extra, which is usually the better choice
var path = require('path');
var compiler = require('your compiler thing');

const generatedOutputPath = 'whatever/your/dest/dir/is';

app.get('/yourshouldknowthisurl.js', (req, res) => {
  let filenameIn = getFileNameForURL(req.url);
  let filenameOut = generateAnOutputFilename();
  let wpConf = {
    entry: filenameIn,
    output: {
      path: generatedOutputPath,
      filename: filenameOut
    },
    // and any other webpack config options. 
  };
  // I'm assuming your compile invokes webpack
  compiler.compile(wpConf, (err,result) => {
    if (err) return sendError(err, res);
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(generatedOutputPath,filenameOut), (err, data) => {
      if (err) return sendError(err, res);
      // Return the actual bundle. Don't return "a url" when the browser
      // requested a javascript file by url. It should get JS code back.
      res.send(data);
    });
  });
});
```

In this, `getFileNameForURL` transforms the incoming URL into a filename. How you do that is your business. The same goes for `generateAnOutputFilename`, how you implement "generating a unique filename" is up to you.

I'd probably even recommend not writing a file *at all* and instead telling webpack to generate the output to memory, so you don't have to write to, and then read back from, the disk. "How to do that" is covered by the webpack documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So, forget about any `webpack-dev-middleware`, you'll use only webpack.

```
const webpack= require('webpack');

app.use((req, res) => {
    const jsTempPath = fetchSyncAndSaveSomewhere(req.url);
    const options = {
        entry: jsTempPath,
        output: {
            path: 'folderLocally',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        }
    };
    const compiler = webpack(options);
    webpack(compiler, (err, stats) => {
      if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
        // do something
      }
      res.send('folderLocally/bundle.js');
    });
});
```

You can't output webpack code to a variable, so you'll have to save locally on your server.

Basically you do:

1. Receive string
2. Save Somewhere
3. Build options object with that entry
4. Run compiler
5. return file.

Comment: i see, so create new compiler everytime a request comes in, thanks will try that and check the performance hit

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only way =/